# SEO: can Google penalize me if i reuse same video / images content for an other website?

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engine-indexing, technical-seo

I created a funny video sites that is containing around 10.000 videos and 5000 images. It become quitly good on my Google local search then now i decided to create a second site that is offering alsmost the same service.

Insteasd finidng again other 10.000 videos and 5000 images and so to have to mantain 2 totally different websites i had this idea:

Reuse same content on the first website as content for the second.

So now what i'm doing is using same videos database and same images database and showing them on the second website but making them avaialble on different URLS with different title and different descriptions.

Let me show you an example:

FIRST SITE: https://example.com/videos/100/title-of-the-funny-video/
Title: A funny video titlte 100
Description: Look at this funny video that will make you happy

SECOND SITE: https://example-2.com/video/100/an-other-title-for-the-above-video/
Title: An other tutitle for this funny video
Description: An other description for this funny videos

So if you check first and second you can see this difference:

- urls are different just sharing same ID
- tittle is different and unique
- description is different and unique

What there is in common ?

1. same publication date
2. same views counts
3. same comments that are showing on both ( at moment )
4. same tags
5. same categories

Also for tags and categories i created their unique title and description.

Every single images and files also if is hosted o nthe same web server is shouwing has hosted on his own domain name separatly from the other.

Sure on both domain directory structure ( where media file are hosted ) is the same, but urls look unique.

Now my question is ...

THis way to proceed expose me to be penalized ? Can i be penalized on first on second or on both websites ?

Please share your experience !
Thanks

Comment: This question isn't focused on images and video, but the same thought process applies when thinking about media: [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)